# Select2 takes 2 clicks to remove focus from a search field

Tags: css, focus, blur, caret

The client has asked for restyling select2 inputs to suit the rest of design, so I overwrote the default css with the custom one using sass.

It's too complicated so I rather won't paste it here...

I haven't touched the original javascript nor tried to overwrite it but now it takes 2 clicks outside the multiple select box to blur input field. The first one removes ".select2-container-active" class from the parent div and shrinks input field to 10px width but leaves blinking caret. The second one finally blurs it.

There are also 2 related issues: that "half focused" caret is bigger then it suppose to be and the width of an input field is dynamically "hardcoded" via style attribute to the maximum when start typing, which causes jumping in a new row.

Any ideas what to do or where to look?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to make the changes (this problem was faced by me in ipad version of my website)

Just copy paste this as it works with select tag.

You need to remove the select2-container-active and then blur the ":focus"

```
$('select').select2().on("select2-close", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.select2-container-active').removeClass('select2-container-active');
        $(':focus').blur(); 
    }, 1);
});
```